# Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition in Swift "Where case" in optional binding

Tags: swift

when I'm using "Where" case in optional binding then getting error

```
if let NewValue1 = MyStringOptional where NewValue1.characters.count == 5{

    print("hi")
}
```

Comment: *getting error*. What error?

Comment: try if let NewValue1 = MyStringOptional, NewValue1.characters.count == 5

Comment: yes it is working now ... but if i want to use Where case then ?

Comment: Error - Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition ....@vadian